# inside/within + time question

Tags: prepositions, difference

I’d like to ask a question.
What’s the difference between these two sentences?

1. The work should be finished inside a week.
2. The work should be finished within a week.

Do these two sentences sound natural to native speakers? For me, No. 1 doesn’t sound natural, and I found on a website that ‘inside a week’ is an American slang. Is it true?

Comment: "within a week" is ok. "Inside a week" is not natural, because inside is not used for time period but it is used for physical things. For instance, "He is inside the building."

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for some native speakers to chip in, here is my tuppence:

Both sound correct to me but to double-check, I looked them up in Oxford Dictionary:

**inside:** 
in less than the amount of time mentioned 
*The job is unlikely to be finished inside (of) a year.*

**within:**
before a particular period of time has passed 
*You should receive a reply within seven days.*